# Azure - Sync Database for Staging Environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, azure

I use Azure as the production environment for my ASP.NET web application.

I am trying to use a staging environment to test a deployment before it is in production.  It seems like the staging environment should use a completely separate database to avoid messing up the production one (esp. to test a new data structure, etc.).

This led me to try setting up a one-way sync so that the production database periodically copies itself to a staging database.  However, the Azure SQL sync does not support self-referencing tables (which are created by my implementation of EntityFramework), which makes it unusable.

Is there another method of doing a one-way sync on these databases?  Is there another way of going about this problem that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. If you make changes to your staging database in the future while developing, and you want to test it on staging before a go-live, the update wouldn't work as it would have a different structure to your live DB.

To begin with you should copy your live database to a staging version and then update that to test as you complete developments. Every now and then after you do a go-live, you can delete your staging DB and restore a new copy from the live site to keep your data clean and up to date for the next development.

Comment: In addition, we can configure connection string in Azure portal when using Azure web app, it will rewrite your web.config connection string, refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/ for more details.